# Question about setg and comparison in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm having problem understanding this exercise. I'll try my best to give my reasoning and I hope you guys can give me an idea what each line of code demonstrates. The Assembly we use is x86
assume the value stored in %rax = x

```
xorq  %rax, %rax // value stored in %rax: x ^ x = 0
addq  $-1,  %rax // value stored in %rax: 0 - 1 = -1
movq  %rax, %rbx // value stored in %rbx: -1 or 0xFFFFFFFF
shlq  $2,   %rbx 
shrq  $1,   %rbx // left shift by 3 total, so value stored in %rbx: 0x7fffffff8
addq  %rbx, %rax // value stored in %rax: 0x7fffffff9
```

For the last line, my professor says we actually computing (TMax-1)-1, which I really don't get.

The question is:

> Assuming the addq from Q3.2 did execute, say we now executed the following instruction:

```
setg %bl
```

> What value (in hex, including the prefix) is now stored in %rbx?

I really don't understand what setg means (I did read the specification but at a lost). Thanks a lot for helping !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note you have two left shifts and one right, so that's not 3 left in total. Also you are using 64 bit registers so the value in `rbx` before the `setg` is actually `0x7ffffffffffffffe`. The instruction set reference entry for `setg` says result is `1` if `ZF=0 and SF=OF`. Well, the result of the addition is `0x7ffffffffffffffd` and that is not `0` so `ZF` is `0`. `SF` being the sign bit is zero, and `OF` being signed overflow is zero too. Hence the condition holds, so `bl` will be `1` but the rest of `rbx` is unchanged giving you `0x7fffffffffffff01`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding RBX to RAX calculates RBX - 1, because RAX still = -1.

I think `TMax - 1` means `INT64_MAX - 1`.

Two left shifts and one right gives you a number with the high bit cleared (non-negative) and the low bit cleared.  The max positive (2's complement) integer is all bits set except the sign bit, and this is one less than that.

Jester explained how `setg` works based on EFLAGS set by `add`.  Look up [`setcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/setcc) in the manual.